# error: expected declaration or statement at end of input atmel studio

Tags: avr-gcc, atmelstudio

I'm new in Embedded systems I am using "atmel Studio7"  so I opened ASF wizard T_C driver for xmega128a1 and modified it to set just the timer TCC0 to count 50 ms and throw an overflow flag every 50 ms beside I commented other timers,
I tried to compile  but I have one error and I can't correct it the error is: "expected declaration or statement at end of input".
which located  in this segment of the code:

```
    void tc_set_ccd_interrupt_callback(volatile void *tc, tc_callback_t callback)
    {

       #ifdef TCC0
          if ((uintptr_t) tc == (uintptr_t) & TCC0) 
           {
             tc_tcc0_ccd_callback = callback;
           }
         else
       #endif
    }
```

anyone have an idea or advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the else word. It expects a new statement after it, which you do not have